# SNS topic not publishing to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am trying to prototype a distributed application using SNS and SQS.I have this topic:

`arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:574008783416:us-east-1-live-auction`

and this queue:

`arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:574008783416:queue4`

I created the queue using the JS Scratchpad. I added the subscription using the Console. I AddPermission to the queue using the scratchpad. The queue policy is now:

```
{  
   "Version":"2008-10-17",
   "Id":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:574008783416:queue4/SQSDefaultPolicy",
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Sid":"RootPerms",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{  
            "AWS":"574008783416"
         },
         "Action":"SQS:*",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:574008783416:queue4"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have an email subscription on the same topic and the emails arrive fine but the messages never arrive on the queue. I've tried SendMessage directly to the queue - rather than via SNS - using Scratchpad and it works fine. Any ideas why it won't send to the queue?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This was posted a while back on the AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=202798

> Then I gave the SNS topic the permission to send messages to the SQS queue. The trick here is to allow all principals. SNS doesn't send from your account ID -- it has its own account ID that it sends from.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. Had an open ticket with AWS support and have begged them to add this answer to the Policy Examples in the docs.

Comment: You'll want to restrict access to the sourceArn: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html#sns-publish-messages-to-sqs-queue

Comment: This is very bad answer. By doing that everyone can send messages from this topic.
Users should seek policies that are allowing them to do things they desire while being the most restrictive policies they can have - it's safer.

i think that your SQS is going to be public after using * as principal.

Comment: example:  https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sns/latest/dg/subscribe-sqs-queue-to-sns-topic.html#SendMessageToSQS.sqs.permissions

Comment: The link to the aws forum has been archived, it is always better option to put the context of the answer you are proposing along with the link.

Answer (score 29):

Adding to Skyler's answer, if like me you cringe at the idea of allowing any principal (`Principal: '*'`), you can restrict the principal to SNS:

```
Principal:
  Service: sns.amazonaws.com
```

Although this behavior is undocumented, it works.

Comment: This is correct answer to the problem. By doing things this way you will not expose your SQS to whole world.

Comment: Wow this was the working solution for me after hours of trying out others, Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I found this documented on step 2 of this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscribe-sqs-queue-to-sns-topic.html

Answer (score 23):

Most of the answers (beside @spg answer) propose usage of `principal: *` - this is very dangerous practice and it will expose your SQS to whole world.

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)

> For resource-based policies, such as Amazon S3 bucket policies, a wildcard (*) in the principal element specifies all users or public access.
> We strongly recommend that you do not use a wildcard in the Principal element in a role's trust policy unless you otherwise restrict access through a Condition element in the policy. Otherwise, any IAM user in any account in your partition can access the role.

Therefore it is strongly not recommended to use this principal.

Instead you need to specify sns service as your principal:

```
"Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
},
```

Example policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1596186813341",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1596186812579",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:SendMessageBatch"
      ],
      "Resource": "Your-SQS-Arn"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this policy sns will be able to send messages to your SQSs.

There are [more permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-permissions-reference.html) for SQS but from what I see `SendMessage` and `SendMessageBatch` should be enough for SNS->SQS subscribtion.

Comment: Do you know if SNS uses `SendMessageBatch` to lower cost?

Comment: This is a fine answer. I'm surprised when I connect SNS to SQS in AWS console, it doesn't do the permission part automatically.

Comment: I like the idea of the extra security, but I have a problem adding this policy to the SNS topic Access Policy. The problem being reported saying: "Policy statement action out of service scope!" After reading the topic Access Policy info - it makes sense. Topic Access Policy controls who can access the topic - not the queue. Trying the same with the queue...

Answer (score 18):

Here's a full CloudFormation example of Skyler's answer

```json
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyTopic": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    },
    "MyQueue": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    },
    "Subscription": {
      "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
      "Properties" : {
          "Protocol" : "sqs",
          "TopicArn" : {"Ref": "MyTopic"},
          "Endpoint": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MyQueue", "Arn"]}
        }
    },
    "QueuePolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "Queues": [
          {"Ref": "MyQueue"}
        ],
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Sid": "allow-sns-messages",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {"Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"},
              "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
              "Resource": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MyQueue", "Arn"]},
              "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                  "aws:SourceArn": {"Ref": "MyTopic"}
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Amazon has more options in their [Sending Amazon SNS Messages to Amazon SQS Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html) document.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Statement needs to include a Resource property:  "Resource": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyQueue", "Arn" ] },

Comment: Ey! Still helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

I just experienced this and took me a while to figure out why:

If I create a SQS subscription from the SNS console, it does not add necessary permissions to the SQS access policy.

If I create the subscription in the SQS console to the same SNS, it does.

Comment: This is a great answer if you just wanted to do it through the Console without having to modify the policy manually. The only strange thing is that it allows any principal but then filters with a condition to the topic ARN.

Comment: Although another caveat with this is that you dont' get any of the other subcription options compared to if you set it up with SNS, most notably in my case "raw message delivery". You can go to SNS and edit the subscription though to enable this.

Answer (score 5):

Like the other answers mentioned, you must opt in and grant permission to this SNS topic to publish to your SQS queue.

If you use terraform, you can use the [sqs_queue_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sqs_queue_policy) resource.

Here is [an example](https://christiangiacomi.com/posts/terraform-sns-sqs-lambda/):

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "your_queue_policy" {
    queue_url = "${aws_sqs_queue.your_queue.id}"

    policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "First",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "${aws_sqs_queue.your_queue.arn}",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_sns_topic.your_topic.arn}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Old question but using an AWS SDK version > 1.10

Check out the docs [SQS-SNS sendMessage Permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html#SendMessageToSQS.sqs.permissions)

```
private static void updateQueuePolicy(AmazonSQS sqs, String queueURL, String topicARN) {
   Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
   Action actions = new Action() {
       @Override
       public String getActionName() {
           return "sqs:SendMessage"; // Action name
       }
   };
   Statement mainQueueStatements = new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
           .withActions(actions)
           .withPrincipals(new Principal("Service", "sns.amazonaws.com"))
           .withConditions(
               new Condition()
               .withType("ArnEquals")
               .withConditionKey("aws:SourceArn")
               .withValues(topicARN)
           );

   final Policy mainQueuePolicy = new Policy()
        .withId("MainQueuePolicy")
        .withStatements(mainQueueStatements);

   attributes.put("Policy", mainQueuePolicy.toJson());

   updateQueueAttributes(sqs, queueURL, attributes);
}
```

Which outputs a policy similar to

```
{
   Policy={
      "Version":"2012-10-17",
       "Id":"MainQueuePolicy",
       "Statement":
            [
              {
                 "Sid":"1",
                 "Effect":"Allow",
                 "Principal": {
                   "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
                 },
                 "Action":["sqs:SendMessage"],
                 "Condition":
                   {"ArnEquals":
                     {"aws:SourceArn":["arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:3232:testSubscription"]}
                   }
              }
            ]
      }
 }
```

Comment: Instead of queueARN you probably meant topicARN.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer to faciliate correct Principal! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled encryption on your queue, can also be a reason for SNS not being able to put message on subscriber queue. You need to give access to SNS to that KMS key.

[This article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-topic-sqs-queue-sse-cmk-policy/) explains how to solve this problem:

Answer (score 1):

only you need subscribe the queue to the topic from the queue console.

- step one: select the queue
- step two: queue Actions
- step three: Subscribe Queue to SNS Topic
- step choose: the topic
- end.

Answer (score 0):

It's by AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy.

You need define a this kind of policy to allow specific SNS perform actions to specific SQS.

```
QueuePolicy:
  Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
  Properties:
    Queues:
    - Ref: MyQueue1
    - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:my-queue-*
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
      - Sid: allow-sns-messages
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: sns.amazonaws.com
        Action: sqs:SendMessage
        Resource:
          - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:my-queue-*
        Condition:
          ArnEquals:
            aws:SourceArn:
              - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:source-sns-*
```

With Lambda this kind of policies dont apply. Please if anyone know why please share it.